# Can "and" be used for the thousands place in sounded-out numbers?

Tags: grammaticality, british-english, conjunctions, collocations

Can "and" be used for the thousands place in sounded-out numbers? Or is it only restricted to the tens and ones places? For example:

> 9,300,000 => nine million and(?) three hundred thousand

Answer (score 1):

I think most native english speakers (at least BrE) would just say

> 9,300,000 => nine million three hundred thousand

However 9,300,043 would be said as

> nine million three hundred thousand **and** forty three

I don't think that it is an actual rule, but conventionally if the last two digits of each block of 3 digits are not both zero then we include "and"  but omit it if they are. Hence 1,100 => "one thousand one hundred", but 1,101 => "one thousand one hundred **and** one" and 1,350,200 => "one million three hundred **and** fifty thousand two hundred. If all three digits of the group are zero then they are not pronounced at all 1,000,100 => "one million one hundred" (no mention of thousands).

Comment: The BBC publishes a [lesson plan on large numbers](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/course/intermediate/unit-25/session-1)  that includes the rules, "Don’t use the word **and** to join millions and thousands or thousands and hundreds [...] But do use the word **and** to join hundreds and tens." So yes, there are actual written rules.

Comment: @CanadianYankee That's exactly what I'm looking for. A source that explicitly says the dos and the don'ts.